# not able to get root window resize event

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to display the size(dimension) of the root window (top level window) on a label. whenever the user resize the window, new window dimensions should be displayed on the label. I tried to bind the  event for the root window but im getting an error as follows

> TclError: bad event type or keysym "configure"

the code i used is given below. Its just a rough sample. Can anyone help me what im doing wrong.

```
def main():
  root=Tk()
  root.title("Test Numbers")
  root.geometry("550x350")
  def d(event):
      print event.width,event.height
  root.bind('<configure>',d)
  root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Case matters

There ought to be capital **`C`**

```
root.bind( "<Configure>", d )
```