# When I enlarge the window, the old background color of the frame appears in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python Tkinter, I use a custom ttk theme with a black frame background color.

However, when I enlarge the window, the part that is outside of the original size of the frame appears in the regular gray color. How do I fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks that the content isn't updating on resize, because it doesn't listen to the resize Event. First Way is to force updating the content by using `after(time, callback)`, next is to use `bind(event)` --> http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm . Maybe you find some hints here?

Comment: SO won't let me edit my comment due to some new 5 min rule. Stupid. Sorry. Someone on SO tried to let his/hers app listen to root resize event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249856/not-able-to-get-root-window-resize-event

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Comment: @Semo: you very, very rarely have to listen to resize events in tkinter -- tkinter does all of that for you. The problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes. I see. The main problem is outdated and very old documentation, where you get millions of "tips" scattered all over the web. It's up to you to choose the right one. ;-)

Comment: @Semo agreed. However, when you make your own "tips" that are vague and/or incorrect, you're adding to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't configured your background frame to properly fill the window.

If you're using `pack`, make sure you've used the `expand` and `fill` options:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

ttk.Style().configure('TFrame', background='#b22222')
backgroundFrame = ttk.Frame(root)

backgroundFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

If you're using `grid`, make sure that you give the row and column of the frame a weight, and make sure you use the `sticky` attribute on the frame:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

ttk.Style().configure('TFrame', background='#b22222')
backgroundFrame = ttk.Frame(root)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

backgroundFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

If you're using `place`, use a relative width and height:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

ttk.Style().configure('TFrame', background='#b22222')
backgroundFrame = ttk.Frame(root)

backgroundFrame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

root.mainloop()
```